# Priority Queue Heapify

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, heap, priority-queue

Is there any way to initialize priority queue with some elements in O(N) complexity? Using the heapify algorithm possibly.

I searched about that problem but couldn't find a solution. Also, I'm aware of make_heap(), but it's another thing and not about priority queues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to initialize priority queue with some elements in O(N) complexity?

Yes; `std::priority_queue<...>` has a constructor for this. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue gives this example:

```
std::vector<int> vec={3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
std::priority_queue<int> c3(std::less<int>(), vec);
```

which initializes `c3` to a priority queue (max-heap) containing the elements of `vec`.

---

**Edited** to reply to a comment:

> what would be the compare function to heapify into a min-heap? I know there is a function called greater<int>(); but it doesn't seem to work for some reason on c++14

So, `std::less` is a bit of a special case, so maybe it's misleading to use it as an example. The `std::priority_queue` class template actually takes *three* type parameters: the element-type, the container-type, and the comparator-type. In the above example, these are `int`, `std::vector<int>`, and `std::less<int>`, respectively. The reason we don't have to write the container-type and comparator-type explicitly in the above example is that those two type parameters have defaults, and in the above example, the default is exactly what we wanted.

To use `std::greater<int>` instead, the equivalent to the above would be:

```
std::vector<int> vec={3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> c3(std::greater<int>(), vec);
```

But if you're using C++17 or higher, you can completely drop the list of template arguments and let the compiler deduce it:

```
std::vector<int> vec={3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
std::priority_queue c3(std::greater<int>(), vec);
```

(Note: this is *not* the same as writing `std::priority_queue<int>` — including any list of template arguments would tell the compiler that you want it to use the defaults for unspecified arguments, rather than using template argument deduction.)

If you're stuck on C++14 and want to avoid having to write `std::greater<int>()` twice, then a *slight* improvement is to use one of the constructors that doesn't require a comparator object:

```
std::vector<int> vec={3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> c3(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend());
```

But using C++17 or higher definitely makes this cleaner. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this idea. It really made sense, sad to not think about it and sorry for bad googling.

Comment: thank you. what would be the compare function to heapify into a min-heap? I know there is a function called greater<int>(); but it doesn't seem to work for some reason on c++14

Comment: @Wira: Good question! I've updated to explain why that doesn't work, and how you can get it to work. (Sorry for the delay.)